# Electron EM Field as Local Gauge Transformation of the Electron Matter Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Taking a simple example, the picture I have of a hydrogen atom is that of an energized (vibratory) state of the electron matter field held in a spherical volume of space by virtue of the attraction of its associated bound EM field with the EM field of the proton in its nucleus. I've seen the beauty of the EM field equations dropping out of a local gauge variation of the matter field in a few lines of math (with the gauge variation corresponding to charge), so that clearly seems to be the fundamental relationship between the matter and bound EM fields. My question is what is the nature of this gauge variation - what is it varying with respect to and what establishes its standard value for the standard charge of the electron?  It doesn't seem to relate to the bound state of the atom as a free electron has the same charge and EM field characteristics, as indeed all electrons do. This seems to be inherent in the process of creating an EM matter field excitation.  I'd appreciate any understanding that the group members can provide!

Comment: To clarify, by local gauge variation I mean a local phase shift in the electron matter field.

Comment: Perhaps I am confusing the Quantum Mechanical electron wave function with the the electron matter field.  Here is a description of the local gauge symmetry I am referring to (not my verbiage):

Comment: There is a symmetry in physics which we might call the Local Phase Symmetry in quantum mechanics. In this symmetry we change the phase of the (electron) wavefunction by a different amount everywhere in spacetime. To compensate for this change, we need to also make a gauge transformation of the electromagnetic potentials. The local phase symmetry requires that Electromagnetism exist and have a gauge symmetry so that we can keep the Schrödinger Equation invariant under this phase transformation.

Comment: So to summarize the question, if there is a bound EM field associated with any higher energy state of the electron matter field, does the local gauge symmetry above imply some corresponding phase change is occurring in the matter field.